# Efi app linker error unresolved external symbol gEfiShellProtocolGuid referenced in function main

Tags: c, windows, linker, uefi

I am trying to create a efi app by manually compiling and linking the source code with MS's VC compiler and MS's Linker.

The source code compiles fine but I get a linker error:

```
    error unresolved external symbol gEfiShellProtocolGuid referenced in function main
```

It would seem I am unable to access gEfiShellProtocolGuid.

Code:

```
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Shell.h>
EFI_STATUS EFIAPI main(IN EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable)
{
    EFI_SHELL_PROTOCOL* efiShellProt;

    SystemTable->BootServices->LocateProtocol(&gEfiShellProtocolGuid, NULL, (VOID**)&efiShellProt);

    CHAR16* cmd = L"ls";
    efiShellProt->Execute(&ImageHandle, cmd, NULL, NULL);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would assume I get this error because I am doing something wrong when trying to manually compile and link up the files.

This is how I attempt to compile it:

```
cl.exe /Zl /GS- /c  /I"C:\edk2\MdePkg\Include" /I"C:\edk2\MdePkg\Include\Library" /I"C:\edk2\ShellPkg\Include\Protocol" /I"C:\edk2\MdePkg\Include\X64" /I"C:\edk2\MdePkg\Include\Protocol" /I"C:\edk2\ShellPkg\Include\Library" MyProgram.c
```

This is how I attempt to link it:

```
link /entry:main /dll /IGNORE:4086 MyProgram.obj
```

Any solutions on how I can fix this linker error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to add gEfiShellProtocolGuid to the [Protocols] section of your application's INF file:

```
[Protocols]
    gEfiShellProtocolGuid
```

When building directly with compiler/linker, you are missing the AutoGen.c file autogenerated by the EDKII tools from the INF file. The AutoGen.c file contains equates for symbols like gEfiShellProtocolGuid and a bunch of other definitions. You may have to replicate those to get your program fully working.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually not using a INF file. I am compiling directly with MS's VC compiler and MS's linker. I am using another tool to take a object/dll file and turn it into a efi. With simple code that does not reference anything major, I can get the code to run in a efi shell. Like a simple "Hello world" program for example. Is there any way you know of to get a reference to this without using an INF file?

Comment: Try to define it directly like this:
EFI_GUID gEfiShellProtocolGuid = { 0x6302d008, 0x7f9b, 0x4f30, { 0x87, 0xac, 0x60, 0xc9, 0xfe, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x4e }};
But then you may get into another unresolved symbols that you would need to bring in.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the responses! I defined EFI_GUID gEfiShellProtocolGuid = { 0x6302d008, 0x7f9b, 0x4f30, { 0x87, 0xac, 0x60, 0xc9, 0xfe, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x4e }}; directly in my code. That was able to compile, link, and run. But when running, the program would hang on a Execute function. I ended up just building the app from scratch with edk2 using inf files. That is much easier. I am finally able to get the program to run the way expected. Anyway, Thanks for all the responses. It is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define all of the guids, pcds and start/stop methods somewhere in your code.

Build one of the applications from edk2 (ex. the efi shell) and take a look at their output in the build folder (ex. X64\ShellPkg\Application\Shell\Shell\DEBUG). There will be a AutoGen.c and AutoGen.h with definitions for all required symbols, you need something like this (or simply copy the files) in your program.
If you need more or other guids just add them to this files.

Beside of the guids, start/stop methods and pcds you need to link against some of the libraries, most likly you will need BaseLib.lib and UefiLib.lib (you can build them with edk2 and then add a reference to them).